# Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS

Tags: html, input, word-wrap

The HTML shown below,

```
<input type="text"/>
```

is displayed in a browser like so:

[image]

---

When I add the following text,

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Using the HTML below,

```
<input type="text" value="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."/>
```

it is displayed in a browser like so:

[image]

---

But I would like it to be displayed in a browser like so:

[image]

---

I want the text in my input element to wrap.
Can this be accomplished without a textarea?

Comment: No, I don't think it can. But why is a textarea not an option?

Comment: Using a textarea is sometimes not an option because you don't want to allow input of multiple lines of text. Just to wrap a single line of text (Note: They are not the same thing).

Comment: There is a solution discussed for this exact purpose with the [CSSWG](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues) for standardization, sadly I can't find the issue though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 not that it is relevant, but some reasons include: we cannot use html5 validation on textareas; we cannot use pattern constraints to validate textareas; a textarea is an unnecessary synonym for an input type=text (it is an input that is type text!) which means twice the styling, etc, etc. In short there are many reasons.

Comment: Also it would be nice to be able to wrap input type=url element. Textarea would not provide the functionality (selection of appropriate keyboard and validating URL and maybe more).

Comment: If JS is allowed, you may use ```textarea``` instead, and use ```oninput``` attribute to remove all line breaks. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198344/6838201) for more information

Comment: Very good question! IMHO shows a lack in the HTML form elements spec! Currently offers: 1) `<input type=text>` for single line content displayed as single line (no CSS overrides possible anymore!) 2) `<textarea>` for multi line content displayed multi line (with various wrap options). 3) **Real use case:** Single line data  which shall stay like this on the server/database (e.g. a filename or title) but nevertheless have the possibility to be multi line with soft wrapping for display/presentation purposes! Currently no HTML native solution for this! This is a real lack in the HTML spec IMHO.

Comment: Literally none of the answers answer the question that was actually asked, which is really wonderful and makes you love the community of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

That is the `textarea`'s job - for multiline text input. The `input` [won't do it](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ktvdu/); it wasn't designed to do it.

So use a `textarea`. Besides their visual differences, they are accessed via JavaScript the same way (use `value` property).

You can prevent newlines being entered via the `input` event and simply using a `replace(/\n/g, '')`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how to collect a single line of input while displaying it wrapped during entry.

Comment: A major problem with this is that a textarea suppresses the go button on mobile devices.

Comment: @Dan It's replaced with a newline button right? That's pretty important in a multiline input.

Comment: @alex Exactly. So if you want real multiline input, then a textarea is better, but if you just want word-wrapped input, then the css solution is better.

Comment: I was about to say that `<textarea>` won't work with things like jQuery's autocomplete, but just change the `<input>` to `<textarea>` and that's all that is necessary.  Hooray for standards!

Comment: As said above: Wrapping a line !== a multi-line string.
I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Doesn't the last sentence "You can prevent newlines being entered via the input event and simply using a replace(/\n/g, '')" answer the question of how to have a single-line input, now?

Comment: @cyclingLinguist sure it does, unless you want the Enter key (or "Go" button on mobile) to work like it does on a single line input, which literally everyone does, in which case it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @DimeCadmium The desired behavior being to submit a form?

Answer (score 27):

Word Break will mimic some of the intent

```css
    input[type=text] {
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-all;
        height: 80px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" />
```

As a workaround, this solution lost its effectiveness on some browsers. Please check the demo: http://cssdesk.com/dbCSQ

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox 43.0.4 and it doesn't work however in Safari 9 and Chrome 48 it seems to work: http://www.cssdesk.com/dbCSQ

Comment: Attached demo by @JasonSperske doesn't work for me neither in Firefox 45 not in Chrome 50.

Comment: The demo works for me in chrome 48 on linux, but the same css in my own page doesn't.

Comment: Solution became outdated at least from chrome 50 :(

Comment: Forget about this solution: does not work with Chrome 74/75, Firefox 63/67, Edge 42, IE 11 and UCBrowser 7.0 (but works with GNOME Web 3.28 - AppleWebKit/605.1.15)

Comment: the link to the demo is broken by now as well

Answer (score 20):

You can **not** use input for it, you need to use textarea instead.
Use textarea with the `wrap="soft"`code and optional the rest of the attributes like this:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="14" cols="10" wrap="soft"> </textarea>
```

**Atributes:** To limit the amount of text in it for example to "40" characters you can add the attribute `maxlength="40"` like this: `<textarea name="text" rows="14" cols="10" wrap="soft" maxlength="40"></textarea>`
To hide the scroll the style for it. if you only use `overflow:scroll;` or `overflow:hidden;` or `overflow:auto;` it will only take affect for one scroll bar. If you want different attributes for each scroll bar then use the attributes like this `overflow:scroll; overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;` in the style area:
To make the textarea not resizable you can use the style with `resize:none;` like this:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="14" cols="10" wrap="soft" maxlength="40" style="overflow:hidden; resize:none;></textarea>
```

That way you can have or example a textarea with 14 rows and 10 cols with word wrap and max character length of "40" characters that works exactly like a input text box does but with rows instead and without using input text.

**NOTE:** textarea works with rows unlike like input `<input type="text" name="tbox" size="10"></input>` that is made to **not** work with rows at all.

Comment: This answer helped me the most; it was clear, concise and to the point. Thank you!

Comment: This answer says, "works exactly like . . . input text box" -- but does it submit on Enter? Because that's an important part of how ```<input type="text">``` works (which I need for browsers with JavaScript disabled), and I'm not currently seeing ```textarea``` work that way.

Comment: It doesn't submit on enter... but could of course attach event listeners to it with JavaScript...

Comment: The `wrap="soft"` is the default, it makes no sense defining it, its opposite is `wrap="hard"`, by which then the text in the `textarea` is wrapped (contains newlines) when submitted in a `form`. When "`hard`" is used, the `cols` attribute must be specified.

Comment: For further info on the latter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974166/2817442

Answer (score 13):

To create a text input in which the value under the hood is a single line string but is presented to the user in a word-wrapped format you can use the [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) attribute on a `<div>` or other element:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');

// Get value from element on input events
el.addEventListener('input', () => console.log(el.textContent));

// Set some value
el.textContent = 'Lorem ipsum curae magna venenatis mattis, purus luctus cubilia quisque in et, leo enim aliquam consequat.'
```

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: I have investigated using this technique, and it has some caveats. I love that it automatically sizes correctly, but it brings in a bit of complexity. For example, if you want to preserve newlines entered by the user, then `textContent` won't work. If you want newlines to submit the form (normal HTML behavior), then you'll need to attach a `keydown` event listener to intercept that keycode.

Comment: Be aware that this allows rich-text formatting, I can for example mark a word bold by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+B.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you absolutely can. This is the code me and my sister wrote for our website for people to input questions and extra information, and it also has a wrapping text box. There may be some things you'll have to change to make it right for what you are using it for.

```html
<div class="product-form__input">
    <label class="form__label" for="custom-questions">
        Your Question(s) & Additional Info.
    </label>
    <textarea class="field__textarea" required style="border:3px double #121212;" id="custom-questions" form="{{product_form_id}}" name="properties[Your Question(s) & Additional Info.]" rows="3" cols="41">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Melanie R. I've edited your comment with the code snippet formatted correctly. Please see this link for how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which was about wrapping text in an `<input type="text"/>` , you are using a `<textarea>` which is a different element altogether.