# Move to new line when input field width exceeds

Tags: html, css, text, newline, line-breaks

I'm trying to move excess text to a new line when there's no more space in the first line. But my text just keep on filling in the same line without moving to another line. How can i fix this? I want to move to the next line when text is filled in the first line.

I already tried

```
word-wrap: break-word

white-space: initial;
```

But to no effect.

My code is like below:

```
<form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
   <div className="create_post_div unchange_div">
        <Field
            name="askQuestionInput"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            className="post_input_preview unchange_div"
            placeholder="Ask your question here"
        />
    </div>
</form>
```

My css classes:

```
.create_post_div{

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.post_input_preview {

    width: 640px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `word-break: break-all;`?

Comment: @KobyDouek yes i tried it.did not work for me

Comment: It looks like you are trying the wrap the text in an input field, which is not possible. If you would show the actual generated HTML and not your server-side script, then it would be easier to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

Answer (score 4):

HTML input elements won't wrap in the way that you're describing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css).

You can however change your `input type=['text']` to a `textarea`, and as a user types, the text will wrap onto the next line. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049243/2648054).

Answer (score -1):

`word-wrap: break-word` recently changed to `overflow-wrap: break-word`

- will wrap long words onto the next line.
- adjusts different words so that they do not break in the middle.

`word-break: break-all`

- irrespective of whether it’s a continuous word or many words, breaks
  them up at the edge of the width limit. (i.e. even within the
  characters of the same word)

So if you have many fixed-size spans which get content dynamically, you might just prefer using `word-wrap: break-word`, as that way only the continuous words are broken in between, and in case it’s a sentence comprising many words, the spaces are adjusted to get intact words (no break within a word).

And if it doesn’t matter, go for either.

Comment: still when i type new text,it continues in the same line.It seems that input field width increase from within

Comment: Doesn't have any effect on the input HTML element which is specified in the question.