# Text wrapping in input area (HTML)

Tags: html

I currently have the following code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label>Some input</label>
    <input type="text" name="var_1">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
```

However, I would very much like to wrap the input text, I have tried to use div class = "text-area" however then as far as I can tell I lose the format, and the input area does not come on a new line. Is there any simple way to fix this or do I have to go with text area? I have looked at this previous post, which is where I got the text-area idea: [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

Comment: have you tired for this issue?

Comment: `do I have to go with text area?` == `yes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use textarea in that case. Try this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label>Some input</label>
    <textarea name="var_1" rows="5" cols="10" wrap="soft"></textarea>
</div>
```

you can change number of row and cols to customize textarea input field size.

Comment: I cant use div class=?

Comment: Yes. I edit my answer. See

Comment: Thanks! Now I have the problem that the text input does not transition into my php script, which is kind of odd. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You meant- you can't catch this input after form submission?

Comment: It does catch the input, problem was that with a textarea there is a whitespace in front of the input for some reason, no idea why, once I removed that everything worked.

Comment: Any space in between textarea openning and closing tags will be consider as whitespace. Unfortunately, there is a whitespace  between <textarea > and </textarea>. I edit my answer. Hope it will work fine.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

YES, TextArea is the only way that is featured by HTML for multiple-line input.

Refer doc :: [TextArea Doc by HTML](https://html.com/tags/textarea/) for more information

Thanks.

Comment: Okay so I should change the class to textarea, where would I put the variables such as  rows="14" cols="10" wrap="soft"