# How can I use CSS to expand a submitted input when text longer than the text window is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a simple to-dousing HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but I cannot figure out the solution to what should be a simple problem. After submitting a task using the Add task button the task appears below the input field as it should alongside an "edit" and "delete" button. However, if the text of the tasks is too long the it disappears behind the edit and delete button to the right of it. May someone explain to me why this is happening and provide a solution so that the task window can expand to fit the larger text as well as the "edit" and "delete" button?

I tried to use word-wrap and set the height to auto but the submitted task continues to be covered if the text is too long.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#task-form");
  const input = document.querySelector(".to-do");
  const list_el = document.querySelector(".tasks");

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const task = input.value;

    if (!task) {
      alert("Please fill out the task");
      return;
    }

    const task_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_el.classList.add("task");

    const task_content_el = document.createElement("div")
    task_content_el.classList.add("content");
    // task_content_el.innerText = task;

    task_el.appendChild(task_content_el);

    const task_input_el = document.createElement("input");
    task_input_el.classList.add("text");
    task_input_el.type = "text";
    task_input_el.value = task;
    task_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");

    task_content_el.appendChild(task_input_el);

    const task_actions_el = document.createElement("div");
    task_actions_el.classList.add("actions");

    const edit_task = document.createElement("button");
    edit_task.classList.add("edit");
    edit_task.innerText = "edit"

    const delete_task = document.createElement("button");
    delete_task.classList.add("delete");
    delete_task.innerText = "delete"

    task_actions_el.appendChild(edit_task);
    task_actions_el.appendChild(delete_task);

    task_el.appendChild(task_actions_el);

    list_el.appendChild(task_el);

    input.value = "";

    edit_task.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (edit_task.innerText.toLocaleLowerCase() == "edit") {
        task_input_el.removeAttribute("readonly");
        task_input_el.focus();
        edit_task.innerText = "Save";
      } else {
        task_input_el.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
        edit_task.innerText = "Edit";
        console.log("Save")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --dark: #374151;
  --darker: #1f2937;
  --darkest: #111827;
  --gray: #6B7280;
  --light: #eee;
  --pink: #EC4899;
  --purple: #8B5CF6;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Fira sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: var(--dark);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  /* background: linear-gradient(black, black), url("images/to-do.jpeg"); */
  background-color: var(--light);
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: saturation;
  margin: 0px;
  /* padding: 20px; */
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  color: green;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul li.logout {
  margin-left: auto;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--gray);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.task-form {
  display: flex;
}

input,
button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
}

.to-do {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  background-color: var(--darker);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.to-do::placeholder {
  color: var(--gray);
}

.task-submit {
  color: var(--pink);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink), var(--purple));
  /* add gradient colors to bg*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.task-submit:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.task-submit:active {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div.metric {
  background: rgb(204, 134, 218);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black, 1px 1px 0 black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

div.metric.one {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  max-width: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.task-list {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.task-list h2 {
  font-size: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--gray);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tasks {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 5px red;
}

.tasks .task {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--darkest);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.tasks .task .content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.tasks .task .content .text {
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.tasks .task .content .text:not(:read-only) {
  color: var(--pink);
}

.tasks .task .actions {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.task .actions button {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.task .actions button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.task .actions button:active {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.task .actions .edit {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink), var(--purple));
  /* add gradient colors to bg*/
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.task .actions .delete {
  color: crimson;
}

div form.task-form {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="account.html">Account</a></li>
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="home.html"><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="Produ-Track Logo"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="logout"><a href="../index.html">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- <h1>Home</h1> -->
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
  <div class="metric one">
    <h2 class="title task">Task List</h2>
    <form id="task-form">
      <input type="text" name="task-input" class="to-do" placeholder="What do I need to do?" />
      <input type="submit" class="task-submit" value="Add task" />
    </form>
    <div class="task-list">
      <h3>Tasks</h3>
      <div class="tasks">
        <!-- <div class="task">
                        <div class="content">
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class="text"
                                value="Go to the gym"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="task">
                        <div class="content">
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class="text"
                                value="Code"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                            <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="metric two">b</div>
  <div class="metric three">c</div>
</section>
<section>lower-section</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: can you create a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

the mistake is that you are showing added tasks as readonly `inputs`, if you just change it as P tags, it should do the trick:

```
  <div class="content">
         <p class="text" value='code' />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to keep it as a readonly input that moves the extra text down one line? Also if changed to p element can it still be readonly until i click edit?

Comment: as far as am concerned, no, you can not write several line in input tag, because for multi-line inputs, html has textarea, see this thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049093/text-wrapping-in-input-area-html/48049243#48049243