# Textbox word wrap not working with CSS (word-wrap: break-word)

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

My Textbox value is more than 20 words.

```css
.customized {
    display: block !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 100px !important ; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control customized" value="@item.value"/>
```

Text-wrap is not being applied to my textbox, tried in all major browsers, did I miss something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

Comment: Thanks @david-schor but No luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not a textbox. You are using input type="text" instead of "textarea"

Comment: I want it to be textbox Matt, for reasons unkown we don't want to use textarea

Comment: You won't be able to achieve it with a input type="text".

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge word-wrap don't work on input textboxes using html or css...Use textarea instead