# How to increased height of MatInput after particular width

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-forms, angular-material-5

Currently working with Angular Material for the chat feature in my application. And I used MatInput for Input Message So what I want, If the user enter text more than the particular width of MatInput then it will automatically move the overflowed text to next line (Like MatTextArea

[image: Currrent MatInput]

Comment: try using css to get the effect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I also try to use MatTextArea which give me the better result for multiple line message but the feature is chatting hence after hit enter the message should send, that is what I unable to did

Comment: For the temporary purpose, I have used MatTextArea with a keypress.enter event which is working fine for me!