# CSS white-space cut the end of the text input value

Tags: html, css

I have a list of inputs that I would like to warp text because it's a crop at the end of the element.

So I used the CSS property: white-space: normal and I tried all others without success because it warps not all the text, the last parts of the text are missing.

Here the result without the white-space:

[image]

Here the result with the white-space :

[image]

Does anyone know why I'm getting not the full text when I warp the text with white-space?

Here my html with one input example:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('candidature/saisirPage?id_page='. $page['id_page']) ?>">
    <?php if($culture == 'en_US' && $page['intitule_en'] != null): ?>
        <input type="button" class="menu_description_no" value="<?php echo $page['intitule_en'];?>" />
    <?php else : ?>
        <input type="button" class="menu_description_no" value="<?php echo $page['intitule_fr'];?>" />
    <?php endif;?>
</a>
```

Here my class css: `menu_description_no`

```
.menu_description_no {
    background:url(/sigap/web/images/with-shadows/badge-square-cross-24.png) left no-repeat;
    background-color: #BBE0EA;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0px 180px 0px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    //border-top-color: #1D384F;
    border-bottom-color: #1D384F;
    color: #284a71;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Update : [image]

Update 2 : with padding: 0px 10px 0px 30px;

[image]

Comment: Mathieu, [This is possibly a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

Comment: @rags2riches Probably not, that question was about **text input** while this one is about **button input** with wrapped text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave fixed height 24px for `.menu_description_no`

try adding:

```
.menu_description_no {
    background:url(/sigap/web/images/with-shadows/badge-square-cross-24.png) left no-repeat;
    background-color: #bbe0ea;
    min-height: 24px;
    padding: 0px 180px 0px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    //border-top-color: #1d384f;
    border-bottom-color: #1d384f;
    color: #284a71;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply it's work it warp realy early in the text as you can see how can i fix it ? i update the result in the post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue correctly, the text inside the `input[type=button]` is cut out and does not wrap inside the button nicely. To solve this issue you need to do a couple of things in your CSS code:

```css
 .menu_description_no {
        display: flex;
        background-color: #BBE0EA;
        height: auto;
        width: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom-color: #1D384F;
        color: #284a71;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="">
    <input type="button" class="menu_description_no" value="first Button first Button first Button first Button" />
    <input type="button" class="menu_description_no" value="Second Button Second Button Second Button Second Button" />
                        
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

When you add display flex to these elements, everything inside the element "flexes" and wrap up nicely. This is in addition to `height: auto` that automaticaly fits the height based on the content and a fixed `width: 200px` that contains the width of the text content inside the value you choose (200px is just there for illustration purposes).