# CSS can't get text to break and start on the next line below with word-wrap

Tags: css, word-wrap

I'm fairly new to css and have become a little stuck on this page:
https://www.cadencepsychology.com.au/anxiety-reassurance-generator/

I'm unable to get the text entered into the field to wrap to the box and drop down to the next line. Instead is just continues to write on a single line continuously.

```css
#wordbox {
    /*opacity: 0;*/
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #black;
    transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
Type in your current worry below, click the "Reassure Me" button, and let our trusty reassurance generator give you an answer to put you at ease so that you can get on with your day*.     
</body>

<FORM NAME="WordForm">  
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox"><BR>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="Reassure Me!" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm);" id="button">
</FORM>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS **cannot** do this. Instead, you'll need to resort to changing the HTML, replacing your `<input type="text">` with a `<textarea>`:

```css
#wordbox {
  /*opacity: 0;*/
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #black;
  transition: 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Type in your current worry below, click the "Reassure Me" button, and let our trusty reassurance generator give you an answer to put you at ease so that you can get on with your day*.
  <FORM NAME="WordForm">
    <TEXTAREA NAME="WordBox" id="wordbox"></TEXTAREA>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Reassure Me!" onClick="PickRandomWord(document.WordForm);" id="button" />
  </FORM>
</body>
```

Please also note that you shouldn't use `<br>`, as it isn't valid inside of a `<form>`. Instead, you should opt for CSS' `margin` / `padding` to control text separation. Also note that your HTML *must* be inside of the closing `</body>` tag. I've shifted your HTML around a little to correct this.

Finally, `color: #black` is not valid CSS, but I'm guessing you may have a pre-processor of sorts, so I've left this as-is in my answer.

Comment: Thank you that has worked perfectly! Yes I was using a pre-processor and then trying to tweak the code to suit which obviously has it's limitations.