# Bootstrap with scaffolded EF core pages - text will not wrap inside of textbox even with inline CSS word-wrap style

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've scaffolded CRUD pages using EF core and I'm trying to edit one of the page's cshtml file. My default Bootstrap CSS file includes the following CSS class definitions:

```
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-md-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 200px;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;  
}
```

I have a particular text box (or  element) that I expect will take several sentences of text. It is wrapped inside of  elements as such:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="ChangeSummary" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="ChangeSummary" class="form-control" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; word-wrap: break-word"/>
      <span asp-validation-for="ChangeSummary" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting that the inline CSS should override any style applied from the externally referenced CSS file. This is what happens with the actual textbox:

[image: bad css]

But I want the text in the textbox to start at the top of the textbox and also to wrap downward like this:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Googled the correct keywords to find the answer here:

[Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

"Input" elements are not intended to handle this type of text wrapping. You have to use the "textarea" element instead.