# How do I make the input group text become responsive if user view it form the mobile device?

Tags: html, css

When a user views input group text from a mobile device they cannot see what they are typing.

How can I resolve this issue?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
        <label><b> Facebook</b></label>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="min-width: 250px; display: inline-block;">https://www.facebook.com/</span>
            <input class="from-control" type="text" id="fb" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) && (event.charCode != 32))">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
        <label><b> Instagram</b></label>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" style="min-width: 250px; display: inline-block;">https://www.instagram.com/</span>
            <input class="from-control" type="text" id="ig" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return ((event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) && (event.charCode != 32))">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to hide input text when the user is on a mobile device?

Comment: If so, [using the password html element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password) would be one option.

Comment: @justinw i want to display the "https://www.facebook.com/" and user will put their username. but somehow in mobile view the field for user to type in their username can't be seen. how do responsive the input group append ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to keep the input visible is to break line. Try to use `textarea` instead of `input`.

This is similar to [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)