# CSS input box cutting off text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue where the text in this input box is being cut off. I've increased the height and the width and it is still showing the same amount of characters. I've also used page-break-after: always and the issue is not being fixed. Here is the code:

```css
    input[division]{
        font-size: 13px;
        height: 70px;
        resize: none;
        text-align: center;
        page-break-after: always
        
    }
```

```html
<div><p><b><br>Division:</b><input id='transfer_out_division' type='text' value="EMD - AFC Program & Information Management" top required division></input></p></div>
```

I would like the text to go to the next line once it reaches the end of the input box. I was trying to make the input box at least 3 lines long. It fits perfectly with  but I do not want to use that element as when I go to print, it prints a line lower and I found it difficult to fix. Input seems as the easiest way to get the printing constraints as consistent as possible.

This is what the printing properties produces when I use textarea: [image]

I would like this to be on the same line for space purposes. How would I fix this?

Comment: <input>s are always single line. If you want multiple lines, you need a <textarea> instead.

Comment: use `textarea` instead of `input`

Comment: use a max-width and `white-space: pre-wrap;` on the inner text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css)

Answer (score 0):

As above...use a textarea

```css
    #textarea {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#transfer_out_division {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="textarea">
<div><p>
  <b>Division:</b>
</p></div>
  <textarea id='transfer_out_division' type='text'
    placeholder="EMD - AFC Program & Information Management" top required division></textarea>
  </div>
```

You will just need to play around with this I have swapped the `value` for a `placeholder` so you can see the content.

Comment: I know textarea works perfectly, but when I go to print the page, it is not aligned with Division. It is printed below the line and nothing I have tried seems to fix this. Might it be a padding issue?

Comment: I would use something like flexbox, let me adjust my answer

Comment: Im going to delete this question and rewrite it with the textarea elements, because I think I made it too complicated and maybe it isnt a complicated issue

Comment: if you use flexbox and align items center like my CSS example it will be all on the same line :D

Answer (score 0):

Although not ideal, I would add `min-width:` to your CSS, forcing the input tag to have a minimum width of your choice. For example:
`min-width: 20%;`

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it so the height and width are equal to fit-content

Answer (score 0):

I am giving the below solution only for the input tag where I have added a custom font but the first character of the font was half cut. So, I added the following CSS line and worked fine
**text-indent:20px;**

full code is

```
#sign[type="text"] {
            font-size: 34px;
            font-family: "sign";
            padding: 32px;
            text-indent:20px;
        }
```