# how to dynamically set a react input height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input

So I have an input field that I want to have its height expand when the content in the input field overflows kind of like discords input field when you message in a channel if the content overflow on the x axis the height automatically increases.

I am using tailwind css and it must specifically be an input because of how i have my entire form designed

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Comment: No I need an input field because of how i have designed my entire form I need it to be an input field

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `word-wrap: break-word; min-height: <default height>; max-height: <maxiumum expanded height>;` to the styles for your input field.

Comment: No it still doesn't work

Comment: [Wrapping text inside input type="text" element HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286663/wrapping-text-inside-input-type-text-element-html-css) It has to be a <textarea> in order to be multi-line

Comment: So it's imposible to have the feature without it being a textarea?